# Json file data in dictionary format

Tags: python-3.x

I have json file in which data format is: [{"data" : max capital loss :2000.0}] [{"data": max capital profit: 10.0} ][{"data": no of trades:20.0}] ]

Now i want to data like this
[{"data" : max capital loss :2000.0}, {"data": max capital profit: 10.0}, {"data": no of trades:20.0}]
 I want to remove the list with comma but whole dictionary data into one list..

Comment: Your initial data is not valid JSON, please format it to be more reflective of the data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is actually of the format above, you can flatten the list of lists into a single list using nested list comprehension in Python.

```
>>> import json

# load json from string (use json.load(path) to load from file)
>>> data = json.loads("""
[
[{"data": {"max capital loss": 2000.0}}], 
[{"data": {"max capital profit": 10.0}} ],
[{"data": {"no of trades": 20.0}}]
]
""")

# flatten the list
>>> flattened_data = [item for lst in data for item in lst]

# output
>>> print(flattened_data)
[{'data': {'max capital loss': 2000.0}},
 {'data': {'max capital profit': 10.0}},
 {'data': {'no of trades': 20.0}}]
```